# Suppose that E and F are systems of events in a finite probability space...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing, information-theory

A system of events in some finite probability space $(\mathcal S, P)$  is:

$\mathcal E$ = $[ E_i ; i \in I ]$

$\mathcal F$ = $[ F_j ; j \in J ]$

The join of $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal F$ is $\mathcal E$$\land$$\mathcal F$ = $[ E_i \cap F_j  ;  (i, j) \in I x J]$.

a.) Prove that both $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal F$ are amalgamations of $\mathcal E$$\land$$\mathcal F$.

---

b.) Suppose $\mathcal G $ = $[G_i ; k \in K]$ is another system in $(\mathcal S, P)$.

Show that each of $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal F$ is an amalgamation of $\mathcal G$.

Show that $\mathcal E$$\land$$\mathcal F$ is an amalgamation of $\mathcal G$.

---

Attempts: I know that $\mathcal E$ is an amalgamation of $\mathcal F$ if an only if for each $j \in J$ there is an $i \in I$ such that $P(E_i \cap F_j)$ = $P(F_j)$

For part b.) Supposing that E, F, and G are events in $\mathcal E, \mathcal F, and  \mathcal G$ and $P(G \cap E \cap F)$ > 0. Then $P(G \cap E)$, $P(F \cap F)$ > 0. Assuming $\mathcal E$ and $\mathcal F$ are amalgamations of $\mathcal G$, G is essentially contained in E and in F.

This is question 2 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=WFArn7VH9TcC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=show%20that%20e%20and%20f%20are%20amalgamations%20if%20g&source=bl&ots=1cGCBZ0KT1&sig=ACfU3U3ii17tHVYLrDxwNs4qkS-Z5DAc2w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwist9Kyh4jlAhWQTt8KHQokBDcQ6AEwA3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=show%20that%20e%20and%20f%20are%20amalgamations%20if%20g&f=false).

Comment: What is "amalgamation"?

Comment: $\mathcal E$ is an amalgamation of $\mathcal F$ if and only if for each $j \in J $ there is an $ i \in I$ such that$ P(E_i \cap F_i)$ = $P(F_i)$. $\mathcal E$ is an amalgamation of $\mathcal F$ if and only if each $E_i$ in $\mathcal E$ is essentially partitioned by those in $\mathcal F$ which are essentially contained in $E_i$

Comment: In (b) how can you "prove  that" $\mathcal E$ is an amalgamation of $\mathcal G$?  Do you have a typo?  Perhaps that's a given condition?

Comment: It’s question 2 on https://books.google.com/books?id=WFArn7VH9TcC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=show+that+e+and+f+are+amalgamations+if+g&source=bl&ots=1cGCBZ0KT1&sig=ACfU3U3ii17tHVYLrDxwNs4qkS-Z5DAc2w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwist9Kyh4jlAhWQTt8KHQokBDcQ6AEwA3oECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=show%20that%20e%20and%20f%20are%20amalgamations%20if%20g&f=false

Comment: yeah and as I expected in part (b) you have a typo.   you are _given_ that $\mathcal E, \mathcal F$ are amalgamations of $\mathcal G$ and you just need to _show_ that $\mathcal E \land \mathcal F$ is also.